# pakage javax.microedition.io.StreamConnection does not exist

Tags: java, android, netbeans

I want to create an application that makes my Android phone as a remote for my PC by connecting via Bluetooth but I have a problem when I try to import this pakage : javax.microedition.io.StreamConnection. the problem is : 
pakage javax.microedition.io does not exist.
I need some help please.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late. But for someone else who visit later will be helpful.

`javax.microedition.io.Connector`, `javax.microedition.io.StreamConnection` are part of `java.lang.Object`. You need J2ME wireless toolkit CLDC (Java microemulator).

You can download the jar file from [jar-download.com](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.microemu/microemulator-app-swing/2.0.0/source-code/javax/microedition/io/Connector.java)

Download and import it your project folder than add following lines,

```
import java.lang.Object;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.StreamConnection;
```

Since you are using bluetooth you might need **bluecave** as well. I recommend at least download and import `bluecave-2.1.1.jar` to work with Bluetooth connections.

Answer (score -1):

You need to download the jar file and put it in your project